# How to prevent SQL Injection when I need to run Snowflake's USE ROLE from the code?

Tags: java, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, jdbctemplate

I am using `Snowflake`. And I have Spring Boot app where I've configured JDBC connection.

I am using Spring's `org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate` to run the following query:

```
public void setRole(String role) {
    jdbcTemplate.execute("USE ROLE " + role);
}
```

Doesn't matter where the role's value comes from - I need to set specific role multiple times in my program, so that is why I have that method.

The thing is - it leaves a room for SQL Injection and I even have a tool that scans my code and complains about that.

I am not sure Snowflake's "USE ROLE " can be used in something like `PreparedStatement`.

How can I prevent SQL Injection here? Or it's not possible there and CodeQL scan result is false positive?

Comment: It certainly looks possible because we don't know what can be in `role` and role names cna have special characters! Maybe you can use `SHOW ROLES` first (no parameters) and check if the supplied role in your code that it matches a valid role exactly before submitting the USE ROLE with the requested role.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I don't think multiple statements can run from one execute. Thus you test `use role role_name; select 1` and see if both statement are run or not. If they do not run you are not injectable.